# Did you know why sass-loader can't able to build while build on compiling?

Tags: sass, sass-loader

How to overcome below error While trying to run **npm run build** scss-loader in webpack.config.js [image: scss-loader compile error]

Trying to run ***npm run build*** facing a runtime compile error.

```
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        option: {
                            implementation: require("sass")
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
```

**This is the error facing**

```
[webpack-cli] Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module.rules[2].use[2] has an unknown property 'option'. These properties are valid:
   object { ident?, loader?, options? }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change this `implementation: require("sass")` to `implementation: require("SASS")` Just remove small letter sass and modify it as SASS.[sass error correction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mxMm.png)